# Visual Basic - random number between 2 points (latitude & longitude)

Tags: vb.net, random

First time poster, longtime reader.  I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out as I'm simply perplexed on how to do this, and I know it should be easy.  I'm trying to use Visual Basic (I'm using VB2019) to generate random GPS points between a set area.

I want to find random values between:

```
latstart 25.761606 and latend 26.676215 -- Latitude
lonstart -80.053995 and lonend-80.053995 -- Longitude
```

The trouble I'm running into is when I try sample codes for generating random numbers, it rounds my coordinates to whole numbers when what I want is for the whole number and decimal to generate random.

I've tried this simple code thus far with no success:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Dim random As New Random
     Dim lonstart As Decimal = TextBox1.Text
     Dim lonend As Decimal = TextBox2.Text
     Dim latstart As Decimal = TextBox3.Text
     Dim latend As Decimal = TextBox4.Text

     Dim templon As Decimal
     Dim templat As Decimal


     templon = random.Next(lonstart, lonend)
     templat = random.Next(latend, latstart)

     Label1.Text = templon
     Label2.Text = templat

 End Sub
```

Could someone please take a look at this and help point me in the right direction? (pun intended or not - you can decide).

I'd like to thank anyone who offers up a helpful suggestion to this problem in advance.

Thank you,

Richard

Comment: `Random.Next()` only treats integers (set `Option Strict On` before anything else). You can use `Random-.NextDouble()`, multiply the returned double by the difference between those two values and add the result to the lower value. E.g., `dim result = latstart + ((latend - latstart) * rnd.NextDouble())`. Declare the Random object as a static (`Shared`) Field, not inside the event handler .

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like you're picking points in an area small enough and far away enough from the poles to be regarded as flat, but if you're going to be using larger areas, you might be interested in [Random Points on a Sphere](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/random-points/).

Comment: For more info, see [Retrieve floating-point values in a specified range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1#Floats).  Specifically the section that starts out with "To generate random floating-point numbers between two arbitrary values".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with some extra code to make sure the values in the textboxes convert to a Decimal (but I'm not checking to see if they are valid lat/long values):

```
Private R As New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lonstart, lonend As Decimal
    Dim latstart, latend As Decimal

    Dim valid As Boolean = True
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, lonstart) Then
        valid = False
    End If
    If valid And Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, lonend) Then
        valid = False
    End If
    If valid And Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, latstart) Then
        valid = False
    End If
    If valid And Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, latend) Then
        valid = False
    End If

    If valid Then
        Dim templon As Decimal = R.NextDouble() * (lonend - lonstart) + lonstart
        Dim templat As Decimal = R.NextDouble() * (latend - latstart) + latstart

        Label1.Text = templon
        Label2.Text = templat
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Was away yesterday.  Thank you to everyone who has offered information to help.  I'll be able to sit down and fully look at the suggestions offered this weekend.  Thank you all for your thoughts.